# View auto scale when "out of screen"

Tags: android, view, autoscaling

I may have a stupid question. But this problem always annoy me.

I always design some `View` (`TextView`, `ImageView`, Layout)
and give them a fixed size, like 300px x 300px.

But when they move out of screen, they always get resized, instead of just being cut.
I have designed websites and programmed in C++ before.
I always paste Image or Text with negative coord, so only part of them can be shown.

But In android, I tried different scale mode, and they only fit for some situation.
I wonder is there any perfect solution?

Here is the example:

[image: Example]

Comment: There are much better ways to hide Android views than moving them off screen. Have you tried using the visibility flags?

Comment: I guess he doesn't want to simply hide the entire view, as the flag would do it. But just show part of it.

Comment: @Mauker, Yes. I need to show part of the view. So visibility or setAlpha do not help.